# Why do the stars in a binary system, revolve diametrically opposite to each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

I encountered this question, as I was reading up on Gravity. The author of my textbook says that the stars orbit a common centre which is their center of mass. I somehow think that this fact might prove helpful while answering this question. But I also tried to counter this claim, hoping that this would lead to some contradiction. So, suppose that the planets do not revolve diametrically opposite to each other, what will happen then. However, my thoughts soon got muddled up. Please help...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the twin star system is isolated, there is no external force acting on it so the center of mass should not move if the system was at rest initially.

[image: centre of mass doesnot move]
Centre of mass doesnot move

---

[image: centre of mass moves]
Centre of mass moves although no external force is applied and the system was at rest initially

Comment: Thank you for those illustrations. So I guess that the fact the Centre of Mass is stationary or not decided whether the stars will be diametrically opposite. But why is it that it happens like this? Is there a mathematical argument?

Comment: @ShreyAryan this was how I was taught this topic. By the way what do u mean by mathematical argument?

Comment: Also, if some object is supposed to be in an orbit arround some other object it needs to rotate aroundi it. If it does not rotate it falls on to the object.